# Android: notifyDataSetChanged is not working

Tags: android, android-listview

The shopping list application I am attempting as an exercise has the following activities:

1. ShoppingListMain - A list of the shopping lists
2. ShoppingListActivity - One that displays all of the shopping list items for a particular shopping list
3. ListItemEditActivity - One that allows one to edit the details of a shopping list item

When I add a new shopping list (in activity #1), the ListView refreshes perfectly. However, when I add a new shopping list item (in activity #2), I have to hit the back button and return to whichever shopping list I added the new item to for said item to appear in the ListView.

I have already tried the suggestions in the following post/s, but still no luck with ShoppingListActivity's ListView.

- [[done]notifyDataSetChanged does not update ListView automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186359/donenotifydatasetchanged-does-not-update-listactivity-automatically)

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

The code that I used for adding new shopping lists...

**ShoppingListApplication.java**

```
public void insertShoppingList(ShoppingList shoppingList) {
    assert(shoppingList != null);

    long id = mDbAdapter.insertShoppingList(shoppingList.getName());
    shoppingList.setId(id);
    mShoppingLists.add(shoppingList);
}
```

**ShoppingListMain.java**

```
    mNewListAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = mNewListName.getText().toString();
            ShoppingList newList = new ShoppingList();
            newList.setName(name);

            mApp.insertShoppingList(newList);

            mNewListName.setText("");
            mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

For adding new items to individual shopping lists...

**ShoppingListActivity.java**

```
    long id = mDbAdapter.insertListItem(mParentListId,
            item.getDescription(), item.getQuantity(),
            item.getUnitCost(), item.isPurchased(),
            item.getNotes());
    Log.i("ShoppingList", "New ID " + id);
    item.setId(id);

    mListItems.add(item);
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListTotal();
```

Comment: Have you tried `requery()`on your cursor? (Or the asynchronous equivalent of swapping cursors since requery is deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void insertShoppingList(ShoppingList shoppingList) {
    assert(shoppingList != null);
    long id = mDbAdapter.insertShoppingList(shoppingList.getName());
    shoppingList.setId(id);
    mShoppingLists.add(shoppingList);
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You must call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() manually.

Comment: It's ShoppingListActivity's logic (adding items to the shopping list) that's the problem, not ShoppingListMain and ShoppingListApplication (which deal with adding the shopping lists themselves).