# Refresh whole listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

I want to refresh whole `listview` in my `android` application.

Basically, in `listview` there are different numbers with their status of busy,off,available etc. So when any number changed his status then i want to change it `image` at that time without `scrolling`.
So how can i do this?

any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the solution posted by AVD above, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your `Adapter`.

Some additional specifics on how/when to call notifyDataSetChanged() can be viewed in [this Google I/O Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method.