# Image is not loading from URL on listview

Tags: android, url, listview, imageview

I am Currently working on Android, and I created `listview` that loads Images from URL. I have achieved this by following code

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL("http://ka.35pk.com/uploadfiles/gamepic/090830121252.jpg").getContent();

Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "pic name");
imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
```

In the `listview` the image is not loading till I scroll down  the `listview` once. But it can loaded correctly on invisible part of `listview`. ie , if I have 100 images on listview means, only 10 images have visible on the screen at a time, these 10 images coudn't load at begging, when I scroll down, another 10 invisible images now come to the visible part, and those images are loaded successfully now, again when I scroll up , now those unloaded images also loaded now, which means that, it coudn't be loaded when it was visible on the screen. Sorry for my English.Hope, I have explained in details. How can I load all the `listview` images from URL without using scroll down/up. kindly help me. thanks.

Comment: You have to refresh list View.Follow link below 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview

Comment: @Hercules your method is not working for me.

Comment: @praba use lazy loading as given by Dhaval's answer or follow this link http://negativeprobability.blogspot.in/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer it is help you:

- **(1)** https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/1168654

and

- **(2)** https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562313/1168654

If your app have many image & also there is memory issue then you have to handle you owen way.

Like download image in listview using lazy loading. and for other images use another way like link 2.

for your scrolling problem check your `getView()` code in adapter add like below:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context con) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return SoapParser.title_date.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return product_id1.size();
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return product_id1.get(position).hashCode();
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ListContent holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tb, null);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.actual = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.targate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
            }



            holder.date.setId(position);
            holder.actual.setId(position);
            holder.targate.setId(position);

            holder.date.setText(" " + SoapParser.title_date.get(position));
            holder.actual.setText(" " + SoapParser.title_actual.get(position));
            holder.targate
                    .setText(" " + SoapParser.title_targate.get(position));

            return v;
        }
    }
```

if you are use any other view in layout then make it `android:focusable='false'`

Comment: I'm trying with the second link.  I will update soon. thank you for your answer.

Comment: I was done this work by using UniversalImageLoader.jar , but still I don't know, what is the reason for that problem. previously I used " InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();" for load image from URL, but now I was changed and working fine. thanks.