# Android How to refresh items after deleting from sqlite database in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistadapter

```
SQLController dbcon;
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    TextView text;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(children);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, children,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder Delete=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            Delete.setTitle("Show Linups Or Delete");
            Delete.setMessage("Press Delete For Remove "+children+" or Press Show Lineups to get Lineups.");
            Delete.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dbcon=new SQLController(activity);
                    dbcon.open();
                    Cursor c=dbcon.returnData();
                    if(c.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do{
                            if(children.equals(c.getString(0))){
                                dbcon.deleteData(children);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(activity,"Successfully Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            }
                        }while(c.moveToNext());
                    }
                    dbcon.close();
                }
            }).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

This is my Group class with List in it,

```
public class Group {

public String string;
public final List<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();

public Group(String string) {
    this.string = string;
}

}
```

This is my Expandable list adapter's getChildView Method, I am using `Sqlite` database and I store data to database and need to delete some items also so i use `onLongClickListener` for Deleting items, when I long click on the item I want to delete a popup appears having delete button, when I click on that button the item from database deleted but the item still appears on that activity until I reopen the application, what I want is when I click on delete button it should be disappear from that list also immediately,
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You need to remove the item from the collection backing your adapter and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update the display

Comment: Thanks For replying, have you post some sample code for how i remove the items?

Comment: Have you help me by giving sample code?

Comment: Where is your list? I don't see it in the code. Or is this a cursor adapter?

Comment: This is my Group class with list in it, public class Group {

    public String string;
    public final List<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Group(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

}

Comment: This may be helpful for you...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598197/how-to-update-the-listview-when-i-click-the-button

Comment: The post you suggest is not helpful it just update the textview by assigning a value to it, i am facing a problem that i could not delete the item from expandable list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to remove the item from the list in this part of the code:

```
Cursor c=dbcon.returnData();
if(c.moveToFirst()){
   do{
       if(children.equals(c.getString(0))){
       dbcon.deleteData(children);
       removeItemFromList(c.getString(0);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
       Toast.makeText(activity,"Successfully Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;
       }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

You just need to search for the string in your list and remove it.

```
private removeItemFromList(String object){
     int index = children.indexOf(object);
     if(index > -1){
        children.remove(index);
     }
}
```

Then when you call notifyDataSetChanged the list should update to reflect the change in data backing the `ListView`. Otherwise if you wanted to run this entirely off the `SQLite` you could use a cursor adapter instead but that would require converting the whole setup.

**Edit**

If you cannot use indexof just manually search for the string

```
int size = children.size();
int targetLocation = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    String indexString = children.get(i);
    if(indexString.equals(object)){
          targetLocation = i;
          break;
    }
}
children.remove(targetLocation);
```

Comment: your method removeItemFromList is not working, what does index.remove(index) means, is it not recursive? remove gives cannot resolve variable remove, and Group.this also has a error.

Comment: that's a typo - its children.remove(index). - As for Group.this, looking at your code above you're removing from within an onclick listener so you may not have been able to reference the list directly. In a callback you would have to reference that differently. Also I'm writing this in the answer, I'm not testing this as I do it. You may need to tweek things and not just copy paste.

Comment: Thankyou so very much Rarw, You helped me a lot my problem solve now with your perfect answer, Thanks alot Sir. :)

Comment: sir its delete the top most item only rather than what i want to delete

Comment: Sir its ow-some, You are great, what a logic Sir. Thanks a lot, Thank-you very much its great logic,