# How refresh a listView inside SherlockFragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a listView inside a SherlockFragment, but I can not update the listView on screen when I make any changes to the Adapter. I tried: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but without success. Thank's.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview/2250849#2250849

Has all the info and things to consider you'll need.

Comment: show some code. you're probably doing something wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be updating the underlying dataset that is passed to the adapter before calling notifyDatasetChanged();

EG:

For ArrayAdapter in a ListActivity 
("arraylist" is the ArrayList you've used to back your ArrayAdapter)

```
arraylist.add(data);
arrayadapter = this.getListAdapter();
arrayadapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, everytime user like press refresh button i repopulate listView initializing `Cursor` again.

Like this: calling this function...

```
public void repopulateListView(){

cursor = dbHelper.fetchAll();
        columns = new String[] {                        
                DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                DBAdapter.KEY_DATE,
                DBAdapter.KEY_VOTE,
                DBAdapter.KEY_CREDIT
        };
        to = new int[] {
                R.id.one,
                R.id.two,
                R.id.three,
                R.id.four
        };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.YOUR_ID,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            }
        }
        }
```

...from `Refresh` onClick:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.refresh:{
            repopulateListView();
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```