# How to Refresh listview present in FragmentTabHost of SherlockFragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, refresh

Developing an application using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), I have two tabs in the same. Both tabs have listview as shown in the image. I need to "refresh" the list of the active tab using the refresh button on the bar. What is the best possible approach to achieve the same?

How to call notifyDataSetChanged of NetworkInformationUI from MainActivity?

Below is the code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    // Declare Variables
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }   

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            menu.add("Refresh")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

            return true;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the view from main_fragment.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);


        // Locate android.R.id.tabhost in main_fragment.xml
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        // Create the tabs in main_fragment.xml
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

        // Create Tab1 with a custom image in res folder
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Network Information").setIndicator("Network Information"), 
                NetworkInformationUI.class, null);

        // Create Tab2
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Trouble-Shoot N/W").setIndicator("Trouble-Shoot N/W"),
                TroubleShootNWUI.class, null);




        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to call notifyDataSetChanged of NetworkInformationUI from
>   MainActivity?

When you click the refresh menu item use the `FragmentManager` to get a reference to the tab fragments, which will be added to the layout in a `FragmentTransaction` using the tag set on the `TabHost.TabSpec`(`"Network Information"` for the first fragment, for example, or you could use your own tag through the `TabSpec.setTag()` method):

```
int currentTab = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
if (currentTab == 0) { // first tab is currently selected
    NetworkInformationUI ni = (NetworkInformationUI) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Network Information");
    // update the list
} else {
    TroubleShootNWUI tnui = (TroubleShootNWUI) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Trouble-Shoot N/W");
    // update the list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but if, i try to update list using  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); it doesnot work..any idea?

Comment: @PowerPC Without seeing the code for those fragments I can't help you.

Comment: i resolved the issue by populating the list again. refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602457/how-refresh-a-listview-inside-sherlockfragment

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
FragmentTabHost tabHost3 = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                        String current_tab = tabHost3.getCurrentTabTag();
                        if (current_tab.equals("abc")) { 
                            ClassFragment ni = (ClassFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("abc");
                            ni.refresh();
                        }
```