# Filter ArrayList and remove unwanted elements

Tags: java, android

I have a ArrayList that contains elements (fields are name and type). There are only two different possible types ("edu" and "ent") that I want each to be displayed in its own listview.

My idea was to create two new ArrayLists with same data and then loop through each and filter unwanted elements like this:

```
ListView listView_ent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.popular_apps_list_ent);
ArrayList<DataHolder> data_ent = data;
for (int i = 0; i < data_ent.size(); i++) {
    if(data_ent.get(i).getType().equals("edu")){
        data_ent.remove(i);
    }
}
listView_ent.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, data_ent));

ListView listView_edu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.popular_apps_list_edu);
ArrayList<DataHolder> data_edu = data;
for (int i = 0; i < data_edu.size(); i++) {
    if(data_edu.get(i).getType().equals("ent")){
        data_edu.remove(i);
    }
}
listView_edu.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, data_edu));
```

There are 10 elements in ArrayList, 5 of each type.

Problem is that at the end in the both listviews there are 4 same items displayed with mixed types.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you probe [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview][1] ??


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview

Comment: I am not trying to refresh listview. If I check what happens in loops I can see that for some unknown reason the ArrayList is not filtered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) copy the data

2) don't iterate using i and remove; use an iterator (remove method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) or start at the end of the list

something like this:

```
ListView listView_ent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.popular_apps_list_ent);
ArrayList<DataHolder> data_ent = new ArrayList( data);
for (int i = data_ent.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(data_ent.get(i).getType().equals("edu")){
        data_ent.remove(i);
    }
}
listView_ent.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, data_ent));

ListView listView_edu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.popular_apps_list_edu);
ArrayList<DataHolder> data_edu = = new ArrayList( data);
for (int i = data_edu.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if(data_edu.get(i).getType().equals("ent")){
        data_edu.remove(i);
    }
}
listView_edu.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, data_edu));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assignment will just copy the value of `data_ent` (which is a reference) to `data_edu`. They will both refer to the same object. So whatever changes you make in either list, same changes will reflect in the other list as well

This is you should do :-

```
List<Integer> data_edu = new ArrayList<Integer>(data_ent);
```

or use the `addAll()` function of array list.

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove an item from your `ArrayList`, the indeces all shift down. You can either add in `i--` after `remove`, or use an iterator:

```
Iterator<DataHolder> i = data_edu.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    DataHolder d = i.next();
    if (d.getType().equals(...) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for for loops, you may be skipping items. Let's say your list is something like that:

```
list = {edu, edu, ent, ent, edu}
```

Your index variable will be `i = 0`. `list[i] == "edu"` then you remove it, but then your list becomes:

```
list = {edu, ent, ent, edu}
```

But your index variable gets incremented and is then equals to 1. and `list[1] = "ent"`. As you undersand you are not processing the first element of the list. You skipped indices.

Hope this is clear.

If you have commons-collections available in your project, you may as well use the filter method on [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29):

```
    CollectionUtils.filter(your_list, new Predicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(Object obj) {
             return !((DataHolder) obj).getType().equals("edu");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Rahul is correct regarding list references, but you have another problem as well.

```
ListView listView_ent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.popular_apps_list_ent);
ArrayList<DataHolder> data_ent = data;
for (int i = 0; i < data_ent.size(); i++) {
    if(data_ent.get(i).getType().equals("edu")){
        data_ent.remove(i);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you remove, you bugger your indices.  You're essentially skipping items.  Consider

```
{"edu", "edu", "ent"}
```

Once you take out the first item (index 0), the second edu becomes the new index 0, but you move on and check index 1.

Try using a ListIterator http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

hint:

```
ListIterator<DataHolder> entDataIterator = data_ent.listIterator();
while(entDataIterator.hasNext(){
    if(/*whatever*/){
        entDataIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your remove loop is wrong. You can use this: for (int i= data_end.size - 1, i >=0, i--)
2. Think about feature extension later? Use more than 2 types?
3. The solution is very simple. Your code a filter function first

   ```
   public List<DataHolder> filterBy(List<DataHolder> list, String type) {
       List<DataHolder> l = new ArrayList<>();
       for ( DataHolder h : list) {
           if (h.getType().equals(type)) {
               l.add(h);
           }
       }
       return l;
   }
   ```

Use the filter function:

```
    List<DataHolder> eduList = filterBy(data, "edu");
    listView_edu.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, eduList));

    List<DataHolder> entList = filterBy(data, "ent");
    listView_ent.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, entList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Guava library for filtering collections:
http://www.motta-droid.com/2013/12/collections-performance-tests-in.html

In example above, filter returns new filtered collection don't affecting source collection. Maybe it's not worth time to add a library for one small task and if collections don't contain much items, but it's a good tool to be familiar with.