# How to change textview dynamically in the slide menu?

Tags: java, android, menu, slide

Is it possible to add textview to slide menu and change it dynamicly?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: sorry about that, android java

Comment: Are you talking about the navigation drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about the NavigationDrawer, it is just a ListView so It is easy to change one of the items dynamically.
See [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and [How to refresh ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview).