# Refresh listview on deleting an item

Tags: android, android-listview

I m new to android programing, i was displaying database content on list view and on click the list view item will delete that field from database but problem is that when click item data is deleted but changes are not reflected on listview. Once when come again to that page you can see the changes.

Comment: reload the listview adapter items or call the notifydatasetchanged

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh Android listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Comment: Show your code...what you tried...

Comment: Did you try lisiview.invalidateViews();. And is it update your listView after scrolling?

Comment: add notifydatasetchange() after deleting the item from the listliew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```