# List view not getting refreshed

Tags: android, listview

I have displayed all the contacts within the phone along with a check box in a list view. Now when the user checks say A and B and clicks on "ok" button, then what I want is to display the list again when making all the check box checked value to false. For that, I have created a method but when I call this method the value of the selected contacts is set to unchecked only when the list is scrolled, else it remains unchecked.
Whats the problem with my code???

Code

```
public void getContactSync(Context context, ArrayList<ContactModel> data) {
        setListAdapter(null);
        contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(context, data);
        setListAdapter(contactListAdapter);
//        contactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

On OK button click

```
Arrays.fill(ContactListAdapter.contacts, 0);
                            contactListFragment.getContactSync(getActivity(), dbHandler.getAlGetContacts());
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ContactModel> data;
    DbHandler dbHandler;
    public static int[] contacts;
    static ArrayList<String> contactsSepetrated;
    public static ArrayList<String> contactsId;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        contacts = new int[data.size()];
        contactsSepetrated = new ArrayList<String>();
        contactsId = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        dbHandler = new DbHandler(context);

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_custom_list, viewGroup, false);
            holder.tvContact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_name);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_contact_checkbox);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                                                           if (compoundButton == holder.checkBox) {
                                                               if (b) {
                                                                   contacts[i] = 1;
                                                                   //dbHandler.updateContactList(data.get(i).getUserID(), 1);


//

                                                               } else {

                                                                   contacts[i] = 0;
                                                               }
                                                           }

                                                       }
                                                   }

        );

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (contacts[i] == 1) {

                    contactsSepetrated.add(data.get(i).getContactName());
                    Log.e("Contact values", contactsSepetrated.toString());
                    contactsId.add(data.get(i).getUserID());
                    Log.e("Position", "" + i);


                } else if (contacts[i] == 0) {

                    contactsSepetrated.remove(data.get(i).getContactName());
                    contactsId.remove(data.get(i).getUserID());
                    Log.e("Contact values", contactsSepetrated.toString());
                    Log.e("Position", "" + i);
                }

                ShareWithinpocketDocs.etContactsList.setText(contactsSepetrated.toString().subSequence(1, contactsSepetrated.toString().length() - 1));


            }
        });


        if (contacts[i] == 0) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
//            emailSeperated.remove(data.get(i).getEmail());
//            Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());

//            ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(emailSeperated.toString());
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
//            emailSeperated.add(data.get(i).getEmail());
//            Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());

        }


        holder.tvContact.setText(data.get(i).getContactName());


        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvContact;
        CheckBox checkBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have read notifyDataSetChanged() here :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh Android listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on click of checkbox inside adapter just call notifydatasetchanged() it will solve your problem

```
holder.checkBox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,
                        boolean b) {

                    if (compoundButton == holder.checkBox) {
                        if (b) {
                            contacts[i] = 1;
                            // dbHandler.updateContactList(data.get(i).getUserID(),
                            // 1);

                            //
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {

                            contacts[i] = 0;
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            );
```

if you want to refresh adapter on ok button click add this to ok button click

```
adapter.notifydatasetchagned()
```

Comment: Nah not working,i tried but the selected contact only gets unselected when i scroll the list

Comment: there is no need of checkbox set on click listener you can do that same in checkbox checkchangedListener

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `setListAdapter(contactListAdapter)`; again inside your `onClick()`