# remove a group from ExpandableListView android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Im using ExpandableListView and I want to delete a group once a button has been pressed in child
Now, i removed the Groug+children from the HashMap and the list but it do not refreshed on listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() call.

once im leaving the Activity and get back the item is removed but I really need it to be removed on click...
please help me
Thanks 
michal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview This post shows 2 methods: invalidate the listview or run `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the UI thread. My best guess is to try those

Comment: I added:
        listAdapter.setData(w.getWord(),x); 

        runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //reload content
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                expListView.invalidateViews();
                expListView.refreshDrawableState();
            }
        });
where setData:  remove(key);
        _listDataHeader.get(location);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: still not being refreshed

Comment: ok I removed the item form the wrong list :-/ its ok now :)

Comment: dude what I did to handle this problem, after deleting the group, I call the Expendable list view and I put a new adapter with a new request, it works fine