# ListView (Inside CardView) visually bugs upon resizing. Gif inside

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, layout

**FIXED: I was incorrectly updating my ListView adapter. see: [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview?rq=1)**

I have been struggling with an incredibly weird bug for too long of a time, and I wonder if any of you have had similar problems.

A detailed explanation of the bug will be less clear than for me to just show you, so I have **attached a gif that displays exactly what goes wrong below.**

http://giphy.com/gifs/xT9DPGixQnDIEHlVU4

Question 5 is included to show you how things are supposed to wrong. Then, when the CardView and the ListView inside it resize because the amount of options changes at question 6, the following goes wrong:

**-** **The colors of the listview items do not get updated according to their correctness. (should be either green or a light shade of red)**

**-** **The checked RadioButton weirdly gets unchecked, right before I click the button.**

*Note: this bug only appears once upon resizing of the Listview. Everything proceeds to work fine once a similar size optionlist is supplied at the next question*

These actions take place upon the second click of the button, which calls the following code

```
                    /*
                    FOR EACH LISTITEM:
                    > Make button unclickable
                    > Animate background change according to correctness of answer
                     */
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentQuestion.getOptionList().size(); i++) {
                        ListView optionList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.optionList);
                        View item = (View) optionList.getChildAt(i);
                        item.findViewById(R.id.optionRadioButton).setClickable(false);
                        final LinearLayout llayout = (LinearLayout) item.findViewById(R.id.itemLinearLayout);

                        int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.lightPrimary);
                        if (currentQuestion.getOptionList().get(i).equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
                            colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.correct);
                        }
                        int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);

                        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = backgroundColorAnimator(
                                colorFrom,
                                colorTo,
                                llayout,
                                i);
                        colorAnimation.start();

                    }
                    // Bottom part of list view is animated SEPERATELY.
                    // please note that THIS DOES GET UPDATED ACCORDINGLY.

                    int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
                    int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.lightPrimary);

                    // Also increments question correct counter (important
                    if (correctAnswerSelected) {
                        colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.correct);
                        currentExercise.questionCorrectlyAnswered();
                    }
                    ValueAnimator anim = backgroundColorAnimator(
                            colorFrom,
                            colorTo,
                            fabContainer,currentQuestion.getOptionList().size()+1);
                            anim.start();
```

**My hypothesis**: Somehow, upon resizing the CardView / RelativeLayout / ListView, the ListView gets reinitiated and I call a different version of it. I suspect this is the cause because the lower part of the CardView (a FAB within a FrameLayout) does change color accordingly.

Any and all help is appreciated, I am at a complete loss with this question

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you saying this bug does not persist, whats your problem now

Comment: What I meant by that is that the bug only appears once when the Listview is resized. The next time (granted it says the same size) it does not reappear.