# Update activity listview from listener

Tags: android

I have a helper class to handle Network Service Discovery, where I declare the NsdManager.ResolveListener, once it resolves a service I want to update the Activity list view.

My Activity onStart

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mNsdHelper = new NsdHelper(this);
    mNsdHelper.initializeNsd();
    super.onStart();
}
```

I want to update back the activity once the service is resolved:

```
    mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);
            mService = serviceInfo;
        }
    };
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest using a 3rd party library called EventBus. It's good for this kind of stuff. Google it, they have good docs to get you started easily.

Comment: Why would he need to use EventBus? He's not bridging Service/Activity or BroadcastReceiver/Activity. Seems like a sledge hammer for a nail.

Comment: Love the comparison :D @AustinHanson

Answer (score 1):

Use Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) to affect some change to your ListView Adapter's backing data model on the main thread. Afterwards, call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). See [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Comment: Wouldn't it couple the Activity to the class?

Comment: EventBus couples a "listener" too - it's just hidden in static classes.