# Refresh Android Activity from outside mainActivity (Adapter class)

Tags: android, listview, recreate

I searched over it and found two results:
Call
1

```
recreate();
```

2

```
startActivity(getIntent());
finish();
```

But I want to refresh the activity NOT from within the activity.

I have more than one fragments, each fragment has listViews which has buttons.

My listView is populated by the data on the server. On button Click I am changing my data on the server and want to refresh all the listViews (so as to make them load new content). The onClick() function is in the listAdapter. So is there any way to refresh whole Activity from this listAdapter class.

OR

Way to refresh fragments from the listAdapter class.

Comment: Use Intent and Open activity itself as you want...this is not an Method but try it

Comment: @SagarAghara that is what the 2 option is doing.

Comment: yes bro. i don't see this...sry for that

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your Adapter. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Comment: Yes. I have read that, but I want to change datasets of multiple listViews. The notifyDataSetChanged works only on the Adapter we are working on.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the context of your activity to your ListView and call this method from your list view

```
((Activity)context).recreate();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.