# How to refresh BaseAdapter on refresh button clicked

Tags: android

I want to refresh `BaseAdapter` which is in `fragment`. I am showing bluetooth list using `BaseAdapter`. I want to refresh this list on Refresh `button` click and want show on `Listview` in `Fragment` .
What should I do for this?

Comment: Simply try to use notifyDataSetChanged() to notify the adapter to refresh the listvew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Answer (score 2):

Try this .

```
public class PersonAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
private ArrayList<PersonBean> mList; 
private Context mContext; 

public PersonAdapter(ArrayList<PersonBean> list, Context context) { 
    mList = list; 
    mContext = context; 
} 

public void refresh(ArrayList<PersonBean> list) { 
    mList = list; 
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
...
```

When click

```
mAdapter.refresh(mList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your data collection, such as Array or List, and do [BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())