# AndroidStudio - ListView Adapter Update

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, adapter

Can listview adapter in JAVA for android studio update itself when a new data is added to it. like if  i have an activity that sends a message and the sent message is displayed on the same activity, so whenever i send a message and add it to my adapter,will it update my listview on the spot or i need to refresh the current activity?

Comment: Use Recycler View Instead of ListView

Comment: so listview doesn't have this feature?

Comment: No, recyclerview is better one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Recycler View` and when the data change in fragment / activity you can add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to update your list

Comment: maybe you can check this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview