# How to refresh recycler view on ui thread

Tags: java, android

I have a  recycler view in my app and I am getting values from the user and storing it in the SQLite database
and then those values will display in recycler view by retrieving. problem is that the recycler view is only updating when I reopen my activity so how can I refresh the recycler view without reopening the activity should I use UI thread? images:
[after inserting item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hswus.png)

[after reopen acitivty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9YH4.png)
I want to display inserted item on recyclearview when the user click on the insert button

here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        button=findViewById(R.id.INSERT);
        name=new ArrayList<>() ;
        id=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.res);
        database=new Database(MainActivity.this);

                button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    database.insert(editText.getText().toString().trim());//insert
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   
                });

StoreDataInArray();//for store database data in array
adapter=new Adapter(name,id,MainActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        }
```

Comment: Can you paste some code of your Adapter for reference?

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview

Comment: your insert method is executed in main thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```